# SwiftUI Firebase Authentication dismiss view after successfully login

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm a beginner iOS developer and I have a problem with my first application. I'm using Firebase as a backend for my app and I have already sign in and sing up methods implemented. My problem is with dismissing LoginView after Auth.auth().signIn method finishing. I've managed to do this when I'm using NavigationLink by setting ObservableObject in isActive:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DashboardView(), isActive: $isUserLogin) { EmptyView() }
```

It's working as expected: when app ending login process screen is going to next view - Dashboard.

But I don't want to use NavigationLink and creating additional step, I want just go back to Dashboard using:

```
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

In this case I don't know how to force app to wait till method loginUser() ends. This is how my code looks now:

```
if loginVM.loginUser() {                    
    appSession.isUserLogin = true
    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
```

I've tried to use closures but it doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle` and `@EnvrionmentObject`, like so:

```
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    @Published var isLoggedIn = false
    @Published var userSession: UserModel? { didSet { self.willChange.send(self) }}
    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()
    
    func listenAuthenticationState() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ [weak self]  (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                let firestoreUserID = API.FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_USER_ID(userID: user.uid)
                firestoreUserID.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if let dict = document?.data() {
                        //Decoding the user, you can do this however you see fit
                        guard let decoderUser = try? UserModel.init(fromDictionary: dict) else {return}
                        self!.userSession = decoderUser
                    }
                }
                self!.isLoggedIn = true
            } else {
                self!.isLoggedIn = false
                self!.userSession = nil
            }
        })
    }
    
    func logOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            print("Logged out")
        } catch let error {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func unbind() {
        if let handle = handle {
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("deinit - seession store")
    }
}
```

Then simply do something along these lines:

```
struct InitialView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    func listen() {
        session.listenAuthenticationState()
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(SYSTEM_BACKGROUND_COLOUR)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Group {
                if session.isLoggedIn {
                   DashboardView()
                } else if !session.isLoggedIn {
                    SignInView()
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: listen)
    }
}
```

Then in your app file, you'd have this:

```
  InitialView()
    .environmentObject(SessionStore())
```

By using an @EnvironmentObject you can now access the user from any view, furthermore, this also allows to track the Auth status of the user meaning if they are logged in, then the application will remember.

Comment: Thanks for quick replay! So basically if SignInView is nested insides InitialView that after ObservedObject (or Environment Object) will change then whole InitialView is rebuilt and condition "if session.isLoggedIn" will be triggered again?

Comment: @ŁukaszStrzelecki It will first check to see if the user is logged in, if so present the corresponding view. If a user is logged in your `DashboardView()` will be presented.